# C++ code that compiles in gcc 9.3 but not in gcc 10.2

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr, c++20, stdarray

The following code compiles in gcc 9.3, but not in gcc 10.2:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 2> opt = {1,2};          

template <typename T>
constexpr auto f(const T& arr) 
{
    std::array<int, arr.size()> res{};
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    auto res = f(opt);
 
}
```

The code is in https://godbolt.org/z/8hb6M8.

The error given by gcc10.2 is that `arr.size() is not a constant expression`.

Which compiler is right? 9.3 or 10.2?

If 10.2 is right, how can I define a compile time array and pass its size (and the array) as an argument?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which one is right but for

> how can I define a compile time array and pass its size (and the array) as an argument?

You can change the function to

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const std::array<T, N>& arr) 
{
    std::array<int, N> res{};
    return res;
}
```

and now the size gets uplifted into the template parameter.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to return an array of the same size. I want to return another size: `std::array<int, size_of_subset_of(arr)> res{}`.  Sorry, maybe I didn't express my intention right. But I have to think how to do it. I asked the question because I don't know why is different the behaviour of the two compilers which means that I don't understand well how `constexpr` works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Antonio You code used `arr.size()`, so that's what I figured you wanted.  To get `size_of_subset_of(arr)` to work, you'd need to make `size_of_subset_of` a function like the one I used here, so that you can get the array size from the template parameter and do some work with that to compute the subset size.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative which works in both compilers and doesn't require changing the template declaration:

```
std::array<int, std::tuple_size_v<T>> res{};
```

Comment: `std::extent_v` doesn't work with `std::array` (only raw arrays)

Comment: @Artyer Oh, damn. I had simply tried to compile it and it does. It just returns 0. Edited to use `std::tuple_size_v` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of constant expressions has been changed since C++20, you can find several changes on [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

The shorter answer is to change your function signature:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto f(const T& arr);
```

into:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto f(const T arr);
```

Then it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/vWeMPq).